# splitting ND arrays using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array and I want to partition it by the first 2 dimensions (and select all elements in the last one). Is there a simple way I can do that using numpy?

Example: given array

```
a = array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

I would like to split it N ways by the first two axes (while retaining all elements in the last one), e.g.,:

```
a[0:2, 0:2, :], a[2:3, 2:3, :]
```

But it doesn't need to be evenly split. Seems like `numpy.array_split` will split on *all* axes?

Comment: Please make sure that your question is complete as described here in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You will get quicker and better responses on complete questions.

Comment: Any examples? I dont get the meaning of `(and select all elements in the last one)`

Comment: The problem with `split` and `array_split` is that they only operate on 1 axis, the results being a list of subarrays.

Comment: I don't have to use `split` or `array_split` if there are other ways to do the same thing.

Comment: You could calculate all the slicing indexes yourself.  It may be a bit tedious, but it doesn't involve anything sophisticated.

Comment: Are you aware that in splitting to `a[0:2, 0:2, :], a[2:3, 2:3, :]`, you've discarded `a[2:3, 0:2, :]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [179]: np.array_split(a,2,0)
Out[179]: 
[array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8]],

        [[ 9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17]]]), 
 array([[[18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23],
         [24, 25, 26]]])]
```

is the same as `[a[:2,:,:], a[2:,:,:]]`

You could loop on those 2 arrays and apply split on the next axis.

```
In [182]: a2=[np.array_split(aa,2,1) for aa in a1]

In [183]: a2    # edited for clarity
Out[183]: 
[[array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
          [ 3,  4,  5]],
         [[ 9, 10, 11],
          [12, 13, 14]]]),  # (2,2,3) 
  array([[[ 6,  7,  8]],
         [[15, 16, 17]]])],  # (2,1,3)

 [array([[[18, 19, 20],
          [21, 22, 23]]]),   # (1,2,3)
  array([[[24, 25, 26]]])]]   # (1,1,3)

In [184]: a2[0][0].shape
Out[184]: (2, 2, 3)

In [185]: a2[0][1].shape
Out[185]: (2, 1, 3)

In [187]: a2[1][0].shape
Out[187]: (1, 2, 3)

In [188]: a2[1][1].shape
Out[188]: (1, 1, 3)
```

With the potential of splitting in uneven arrays in each dimension, it is hard to do this in a full vectorized form.  And even if the splits were even it's tricky to do this sort of grid splitting because values are not contiguous.  In this example there's a gap between `5` and `9` in the first subarray.

Answer (score 0):

A quick list comprehension will do the trick

```
[np.array_split(arr, 2, axis=1)
 for arr in np.array_split(a, 2, axis=0)]
```

This will result in a list of lists, the items of which contain the arrays you're looking for.